# MVC 3 Client side date validation issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, datetimepicker, client-side-validation

I have some problems with client-side validation DateTime fields. I'm using following 
DataAnnotation in my model class to DateTime fields:

```
[Display(Name = "Beginning Date", Description = @"Insert Date yyyy-mm-dd")]
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = @"Insert Date yyyy-mm-dd")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

I'm using Datapicker from jQuery UI to insert date. Date format is enforced by

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
 });
```

So it works great on Firefox but completely crash on Internet Explorer when I insert date using Datepicker. When I type date in format yyyy/mm/dd instead of yyyy-mm-dd then is no validation error.

Does anyone  know why the validation format is different on Internet Explorer than Firefox and where I can change it?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 7):

You can replace the `date` validator with the `dateISO` validator.

```
$.validator.methods["date"] = function (value, element) {
    return $.validator.methods.dateISO.apply(this, arguments); 
};
```

By default, the [jQuery date validation method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/date) uses JavaScript's built-in `Date` object to test if the date is valid. Internet Explorer 8 and below do not support using the ISO Date Format for the `Date` object (see [JavaScript Version Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/s4esdbwz%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)), which causes the validation to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this blog post:
[ASP.NET MVC 3: Integrating with the jQuery UI date picker and adding a jQuery validate date range validator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx). Might be helpful.